# Code that produces plot in V5 doesn't work in later versions

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, special-functions, convergence

I have problem in plotting Integral function.

I can compute/plot the graph of this integration below in Mathematica 5.0, but it is not possible to plot it in higher Mathematica versions.

My code is:

```
w = 100
b = 438095.2 (2.5*10^6 + 547826*y^2)
d = Sqrt[-8.8*10^21 *y^2 + 1.92*10^11 *(2.52*10^6 + 547826*y^2)^2]
p = (-b - d)/2
p1 = (-b + d)/2
T = 10^18 *Sqrt[π/2]*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + w^2)^3]*1/
d*(1 - Erf[(p*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*
Exp[(p*10^-15)^2/2 - p*10^-15*(1 - τ)]*y*w, {y, 0, ∞}, 
Method -> Oscillatory, MaxRecursion -> 12]
Plot[T, {τ, 0, 6*10^3}]
```

The plot is generated by Mathematica 5.0:

[image: plot]

Error in later versions is NIntegrate::nconv

Can anybody please help? Any suggestions appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post your code rather than a picture so that the code can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook.

Comment: why is $p_1$ defined but not used anywhere? Add you also do not a value for $\tau$ defined anywhere but using it inside a numerical integration. How did this work in V 5? And there is no need to use subscripts, makes the code hard to read. Simply `p2`write  instead `Subscript[p, 2] `

Comment: p1 is defined for another integral, I didn't mention it. Yes it works in V5, because at last, in Plot part all the variables are integrated. Can you suggest me another way of writing for this?  I am a new user of Mathematica don't pay attention at subscripts  :)

Comment: `Yes it works in V5` how could numerical integral work when there is undefined symbol (in your case $\tau$) inside it, other than the integration variable? This makes little sense to me as numerical integration needs numerical values for all parameters. Could you show screen shot, from clean kernel showing it works? This will help clarify things.

Comment: @Nasser  you can realised it like this
Plot[10^18 *Sqrt[\[Pi]/2]*
  NIntegrate[
   BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + w^2)^3]*1/
    d*(1 - Erf[(p*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*
    Exp[(p*10^-15)^2/2 - 
      p*10^-15*(1 - \[Tau])]*y*w, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}], {\[Tau], 0, 6*10^3}]

Comment: but that is NOT the code you posted. In the code you show, you are doing the integration FIRST where $\tau$ has no value. Then after the integration is completed,  you then do the plot using $\tau$ as the plot variable. Did you try to run the code you posted to see if it works in V5? It can't work as is.

Comment: Dear @Nasser, the screenshots that I provided above is generated with the original  version of code, i.e:                             T=NIntegrate[....]    Plot[T,{Tau,0,6000}]

Comment: The integral is divergent.  The code in V5 produced the wrong result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The integral diverges, please see [Michael's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225408/1871) for more detail. This is just an answer reproducing result of *v5*.

Unlike higher versions, *v5* is using very few points for the generation of graphic:

```
plot = Plot[T, {τ, 0, 6*10^3}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {32.1406250 Second, Null} *)

plot[[1, 1, 1, 1]]
% // Length
```

[image]

To obtain the result in a reasonable time in higher versions, just limit the points for plotting:

```
Quiet@Plot[T, {τ, 0, 6*10^3}, MaxRecursion -> 0] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Still a bit slower than *v5*, but acceptable in my view.

---

### Update: A More General Solution

The solution above works at least in *v12.0.1*, *v12.1.1* and *v11.3*, but in *v8.0.4* and *v9.0.1* samples like

```
T /. τ -> 1 // AbsoluteTiming
```

returns unevaluated (to be precise, `NIntegrate[…]` therein returns unevaluated) after `nconv` warning generates. If one still needs the result in *v5*, a possible approach is to implement the `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` method ourselves as I've done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113301/1871):

```
Clear[int, separateint]
zero[i_] = Piecewise[{{BesselJZero[0, i], i > 0}}]; 
separateint[f_, t_, i_?NumericQ, prec_] := 
 NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y] f[y, t], {y, zero@i, zero[i + 1]}, WorkingPrecision -> prec, 
  MaxRecursion -> 40]; 
int[f_, t_?NumericQ, prec_ : MachinePrecision] := 
 NSum[separateint[f, t, i, prec], {i, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns", 
  WorkingPrecision -> prec];
```

The usage of `int` is as follows:

```
Clear@func;
func[y_, τ_] = 
  1/Sqrt[(y^2 + w^2)^3]*1/d*(1 - Erf[(p*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*
   Exp[(p*10^-15)^2/2 - p*10^-15*(1 - τ)]*y*w;

T = 10^18*Sqrt[π/2]*int[func, τ];

T /. τ -> 1
(* 84.0182 *)

Plot[T, {τ, 0, 6*10^3}, MaxRecursion -> 0] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The resulting graphic is the same as shown above, but the solution also works in *v8.0.4* and *v9.0.1*.

This solution also works for the `Tc` and `Td` in your [new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225276/1871), on which `NIntegrate` of *v12* again returns unevaluated.

Comment: XZCZD thanks for advice. Can you give me your contact info if I send you another case of the problem. I'm really  confused.

Comment: @IsmatovTolib I'm sorry, but it's my stupid insistence that I only discuss Mathematica in public. Just ask your question in this site, if I find it interesting and know the solution, I'll answer. (Do remember to make the question [on-topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). )

Comment: I asked another question about my whole problem. The same problembut a little bit complex function. Can you see please. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: XZCZD by using which math version you produced the graph above?

Comment: @IsmatovTolib Check my update. You'd better mention the version of your Mathematica in your question, too.

Comment: I should add the note that yes, the old `Oscillatory` method in pre-version 6, and the equivalent `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` method in newer versions, are able to evaluate divergent oscillatory integrals in [the Abel sense](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.15.E30), so depending on what you're doing, you have to be careful. Here's one of my favorite examples: `NIntegrate[Log[x] Sin[x], {x, 0, ∞}, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 25]` and compare with `Limit[LaplaceTransform[Log[x] Sin[x], x, t], t -> 0]`.

Answer (score 5):

### This is not a bug.  It's an improvement. The integral is divergent.

The V5 `Oscillatory` method is defunct. `NIntegrate` chooses the `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` method (which is the method it chooses for this integral if `Method -> Automatic`).  This method checks convergence, and the amplitude of the oscillations goes to infinity.  Therefore you cannot apply this method.  Whether or not one can make sense of the integral or series used in the extrapolating oscillatory method by applying methods for divergent series, I did not look further into.  The nice shape of the graph suggests something like [Euler's approach to $\sum (-1)^n n!x^{n+1}$](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/247/) might be possible.

**Analytic divergence.**
Let's define the integrand two ways, the original machine-precision one as `integrand0` and the rationalized, exact one as `integrand`.

```
integrand = Rationalize[
   Rationalize[
    integrand0 = 
     BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + w^2)^3]*1/
       d*(Erfc[(p*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*
      Exp[(p*10^-15)^2/2 - p*10^-15*(1 - τ)]*y*w
    ],
   0];
```

The aymptotic expansion of `BesselJ[0, y]` has a leading term proportional to `1/Sqrt[y]`:

```
Normal@Series[BesselJ[0, y], {y, Infinity, 0}]
```

> ```
> (*  (Sqrt[2/π] Cos[π/4 - y])/Sqrt[y]  *)
> ```

To check convergence, the `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` strategy replaces `BesselJ[0, y]` by `1/Sqrt[y]` and takes the limit at infinity.  This results in `ComplexInfinity`, even if `τ` does not have a numeric value:

```
Limit[integrand0 /. _BesselJ -> 1/Sqrt[y], y -> Infinity]
```

> ```
> (*  ComplexInfinity  *)
> ```

```
Limit[integrand /. _BesselJ -> 1/Sqrt[y], y -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> τ > 0]
```

> ```
> (*  Infinity  *)
> ```

(The exact limit is difficult for `Limit` to evaluate without some helpful assumption about `τ`.)  We can see the actual limit use in the following trace:

```
ClearSystemCache[] (* Asymptotics`ClassicLimit caches some results *)
Trace[
  10^18*Sqrt[π/2]*
   NIntegrate[
    BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + w^2)^3]*1/
      d*(Erfc[(p*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*
     Exp[(p*10^-15)^2/2 - p*10^-15*(1 - τ)]*y*w,
    {y, 0, ∞},
    Method -> Oscillatory,(* defunct method *)
    MaxRecursion -> 12],
  _Asymptotics`ClassicLimit,
  TraceInternal -> True, TraceForward -> True] /. 
 x_Times /; Simplify[x - integrand0 /. _BesselJ -> 1/Sqrt[y]] == 0 -> 
  "integrand0"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Numerical divgence 1.**
We've seen that things in *Mathematica* can go wrong, so we should look for further verification.

Here is an evaluation of the integrand at increasing powers of `2`.

```
Block[{τ = 1000},
 integrand /. y -> N[2^Range@14, 16] // RealExponent
 ]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {-17.3277, -18.4065, -23.9926, -44.2635, -124.654, -444.958,
>    -1723.93, -6791.65, -26461., -95463.2, -216725., 1.77412*10^6, 
>    4.93517*10^7, 8.7349*10^8}
> *)
> ```

Note these are the exponents (base $10$).
Initially, the integrand seems to converge very rapidly to zero (down to $10^{-216725}$).  This is why `NIntegrate` misses the divergence in `Plot`: `Plot` applies `N` to `NIntegrate` when it first returns unevaluated, and `N[NIntegate[..]]` somehow forces the fall-back method of the `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` strategy, which by default is `"GlobalAdaptive"` with `"GaussKronrodRule"`.  The `"GaussKronrodRule"` fails to detect divergence for smaller values of `τ` because it samples only in the apparently-convergence part of the domain.

However, it can be seen that the amplitude takes off, reaching $10^{10^8}$ at $y = 16384$.

**Numerical divergence 2.**
As another confirmation, we can modify @xzczd's implementation of the extrapolating oscillatory method.  We add `NSumTerms -> 100`:

```
int[f_, t_?NumericQ, prec_ : MachinePrecision] := 
 NSum[separateint[f, t, i, prec], {i, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns", 
  NSumTerms -> 100
  WorkingPrecision -> prec];
```

Then we get a much different result:

```
T /. τ -> 1
```

> ```
> (*  2.09192*10^153  *)
> ```

---

*My original answer is only partly right, but using a proper definition turned out to be a minor side issue. Here's an easier way to get plot of the "value" of the integral.  Erelyi's approach to Euler's sum for $\sum (-1)^n n!x^{n+1}$ in *Asymptotic Expansions* is to observe that for small $x$, "the terms of the series at first decrease quite rapidly, and an approximate numerical value of [the sum] may be computed."  Likewise we can truncate the interval of integration near the minimum amplitude and cut off the divergent part.  No analysis has been made of whether this value can be considered equivalent to the integral, whether in the sense of Euler's paper or in some other way.*

```
ClearAll[T];
T[τ0_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{τ = SetPrecision[τ0, Infinity]},
   10^18*Sqrt[π/2]*NIntegrate[integrand,
     Evaluate@{y, 0, 
       Max[15, First@
         FindArgMin[
          integrand /. _BesselJ -> 1/Sqrt[y], {y, 50 + τ, 0, 
           10000}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
        ]}, MaxRecursion -> 12]
   ];

Plot[T[τ1], {τ1, 0, 6*10^3}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> [image]

*Original answer*

The problem (for V12.1.1) is that `T` is not properly defined.  Making it a function of `τ` gets rid of all error/warning messages:

```
ClearAll[T];
T[τ_?NumericQ] := 
  10^18*Sqrt[π/2]*
   NIntegrate[
    BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + w^2)^3]*1/
      d*(Erfc[(p*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*
     Exp[(p*10^-15)^2/2 - p*10^-15*(1 - τ)]*y*w,
    {y, 0, ∞}, MaxRecursion -> 12];
Plot[T[τ], {τ, 0, 6*10^3}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> [image]

Comment: The way to define `T` isn't too big a problem here. I've tested both, the timing is similar. (One needs to test with a fresh kernel, the timing reduces significantly after the first run. ) I think the real problem is a bug of `NIntegrate`, see the update to my answer. BTW the warning `nconv` is still there using this method. Tested on _v12.1.1_, Win10.

Comment: @xzczd What's the timing got to do with it? I thought the OP's problem was producing the graph. I get no error messages. (You can `ClearSystemCache[]` instead of restarting the kernel.)

Comment: I just mean `τ_?NumericQ` actually helps little, the original `T` also works in _v12.1.1_, and the performance is almost the same.

Comment: @xzczd I made a mistake, but I think we both did.  I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: Oh… I did suspect the integral diverges, but the moment I see the result of self-implementation of `ExtrapolatingOscillatory` I forgot everything… I've edited my answer accordingly, thx for pointing out, but…"This is why `NIntegrate` misses the divergence in `Plot`: `Plot` applies `N` to `NIntegrate` when it first returns unevaluated, and `N[NIntegate[..]]` somehow forces the fall-back method " This isn't quite right, because `NIntegrate[integrand0 /. τ -> 1, {y, 0, ∞}]` evaluates. Or you actually mean `NIntegrate[integrand, …`?

Comment: @xzczd Try `Block[{\[Tau] = 2}, 10^18*Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] * NIntegrate[integrand0, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 12]]`.  I think tau has to be at least `2`. But now I'm not sure how `Plot` does the graph.  I'll work on it...

Comment: @xzczd The `Plot` doesn't work with `integrand0`, but it does with `Plot[Evaluate@integrand0,...]`.  It must literally numericize the argument (for when that happens, it passes the convergence test).

Comment: Ah, I knew [we've discussed Abel/Cesàro summability](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107904) before...