# Plotting a complex integral function

Tags: plotting, numerics, convergence

Can anybody help me to plot the `T1` and `T2`, please?

The problem is that the integral part becomes so huge or indeterminate at some points. So how do I find and skip such points?

```
b = (2.3*10^16)/(2.5*10^6*2.1*10^4)*(2.5*10^6 + 2.1*10^4 + (2.5*10^6)/(2.3*10^16)*2.1*10^4*(y/(100*2.5*10^-9))^2)
d = Sqrt[b^2 - 4*315*(y/(100*2.5*10^-9))^2*(2.3*10^16)/(2.5*10^6*2.1*10^4)]
p1 = -(b - d)/2
p2 = -(b + d)/2
T1 = (1.58*10^-5*2.3*10^16*10^-15)/((2*π)^1.5*0.84*2.5*10^-18*10^-15*2.5*10^6*2.1*10^4)*Sqrt[π/2]*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + 100^2)^3]*1/d*((1 - Erf[(p1*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*Exp[(p1*10^-15)^2/2 - p1*10^-15*(1 - t)] - (1 -Erf[(p2*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*Exp[(p2*10^-15)^2/2 - p2*10^-15*(1 - t)])*y*50, {y, 0, ∞}]
T2 = T1 + (1.58*10^-5*10^-15)/((2*π)^1.5*0.84*2.5*10^-18*10^-15*2.1*10^4)*Sqrt[π/2]*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + 100^2)^3]*1/d*(p1*(1 - Erf[(p1*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*Exp[(p1*10^-15)^2/2 - p1*10^-15*(1 - t)] - p2*(1 - Erf[(p2*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*Exp[(p2*10^-15)^2/2 - p2*10^-15*(1 - t)])*y*100, {y, 0, ∞}]
Plot[T1, {t, 0.01, 6000}]  
Plot[T2, {t, 0.01, 6000}]
```

If I write `T1` and `T2` like `T1=Ta+Tb`, `T2=T1+Tc+Td` (evaluationg integral members separately) it works in V5:

```
b = (2.3*10^16)/(2.5*10^6*2.1*10^4)*(2.5*10^6 + 2.1*10^4 + (2.5*10^6)/(2.3*10^16)*2.1*10^4*(y/(100*2.5*10^-9))^2)
d = Sqrt[b^2 - 4*315*(y/(100*2.5*10^-9))^2*(2.3*10^16)/(2.5*10^6*2.1*10^4)]
p1 = -(b - d)/2
p2 = -(b + d)/2
Ta = (1.58*10^-5*2.3*10^16*10^-15)/((2*π)^1.5*0.84*2.5*10^-18*10^-15*2.5*10^6*2.1*10^4)*Sqrt[π/2]*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + 100^2)^3]*1/d*((1 - Erf[(p1*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*Exp[(p1*10^-15)^2/2 - p1*10^-15*(1 - t)])*y*100, {y, 0, ∞}]

Tb = (1.58*10^-5*2.3*10^16*10^-15)/((2*π)^1.5*0.84*2.5*10^-18*10^-15*2.5*10^6*2.1*10^4)*Sqrt[π/2]*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + 100^2)^3]*1/d*(-(1 -Erf[(p2*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*Exp[(p2*10^-15)^2/2 - p2*10^-15*(1 - t)])*y*100, {y, 0, ∞}]

Tc = (1.58*10^-5*10^-15)/((2*π)^1.5*0.84*2.5*10^-18*10^-15*2.1*10^4)*Sqrt[π/2]*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + 100^2)^3]*1/d*(p1*(1 - Erf[(p1*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*Exp[(p1*10^-15)^2/2 - p1*10^-15*(1 - t)])*y*100, {y, 0, ∞}]
Td = (1.58*10^-5*10^-15)/((2*π)^1.5*0.84*2.5*10^-18*10^-15*2.1*10^4)*Sqrt[π/2]*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]/Sqrt[(y^2 + 100^2)^3]*1/d*(-p2*(1 - Erf[(p2*10^-15 - 1)/Sqrt[2]])*Exp[(p2*10^-15)^2/2 - p2*10^-15*(1 - t)])*y*100, {y, 0, ∞}]
Plot[Ta+Tb, {t, 0.01, 6000}]  
Plot[Ta+Tb+Tc+Td, {t, 0.01, 6000}]
```

T1:

[image]

T2:

[image]

Obviously, some points are missing, but it is still helpful. At least, I can say that my calculation are correct :)

Comment: You have `(1 - t)` in your integrals, but t is neither defined, nor the variable of integration. On top of that the integral is highly oscillatory, but the `(1-t)` issue needs fixing first.

Comment: @flinty It seems `t` is the parameter, see `Plot[T1, {t, 0.01, 6*10^3}]`

Comment: Since you're plotting over `t`, you should change T1,T2 into functions of `t` so replace T1 and T2 with `T1[t_?NumericQ] := ...` and `T2[t_?NumericQ] := T1[t] + ...`. That fixes problem 1. The remaining problem is that now we can evaluate T1, we have `T1[2.0]`  giving `7.209952984984601*10^37881` which is huge and off the scale.

Comment: @Bill yes, as I increase y-perameter, T1 becomes so huge  OR indeterminate  at some points as FLINTY mentioned previously. So, how to skip that points? Maybe by considering low precision or some approximations :-(

Comment: I don't think this is a problem that can be resolved by skipping a few points when plotting, if `T1` and `T2` should not be so huge, their definitions need to be doube-checked. BTW this time the code doesn't even _work_ in _v5_.

Comment: @xzczd it works in V5 when T1 is evaluated seperately. Like:  T1=Ta-Tb      Ta=...Nintegrate[F[p1]...]    Tb=...Nintegrate[F[p2]...]     Plot[Ta-Tb]. T2 is also works when evaluated in this manner but only in V5. I discovered this actually by coincidence. So can anybody explain what is the difference between V5 and new versions?

Comment: Then please show us the code works in v5.

Comment: @xzczd I added the code at the endof the post

Comment: I've updated my previous answer, the new added solution works for your new problem now. Notice you need to adjust the domain of `t` to e.g. `{t, 500, 6*10^3}`.